# Relation with pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I've three tables and I would like to use pivot table data when getting results.

These tables are products, store, store_products, cart_items and their fields are below:

- products (id, name, price)
- store (id, name etc.)
- store_products (store_id, product_id, store_price, store_slug)
- cart_items (id, user_id, product_id, store_id, quantity)

My CartItem model is like

```
class CartItem extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Store');
    }

}
```

When I call `CartItem::with('product')->get()`, I would like it to return product data `(from product table and store_price, store_slug from store_products)` with matching `cart_items.store_id and cart_items.product_id` from pivot table `"store_products"`.

How can I create this relation by on my CartItem model? If possible, by just using Eloquent ORM functions instead of query builder or raw queries.

Answer (score 0):

In products Model add,

```
public function stores(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class)->withPivot('store_price', 'store_slug');
}
```

In Store Model add,

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Products::class)->withPivot('store_price', 'store_slug');
}
```

Then call,

```
CartItem::with(['product.stores'])->get();
```

For more explanation read this article:

http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but that doesn't return correct result. This is including product data to CartItem with all stores in pivot table. What I want to do is getting pivot result for specific store_id which defined in each CartItem row

Comment: Try this one `CartItem::with(['store.products'])->get();`